# Stored procedure not compiling with different USE clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have several views in Database 1 and I wrote a stored procedure in database 2. The stored procedure in database 2 references several tables in database 1.

For some reason when I have:

```
USE Database1
GO
```

while testing, it works completely fine. But when I use

```
USE Database2
GO
```

the stored procedure doesn't compile. No warnings, just continues to spin. The first case only takes about 1 second to run.

Anyone know what could possibly be the issue? When I attempt to run similar stored procedures in database2 that use the same references to database1 it works fine. Also, they are on the same server in SQL Server.

Sorry I am unable to post the code.

Comment: Without the code, it's going to be difficult to determine what your issue is. There could be another bit of your stored procedure that is causing the problem. If you are concerned about security, change your table names to something else in your example.

Comment: It could be any number of things. Are you trying to create these procs or is this when executing them? I have a feeling it is when executing. This is definitely a sign of blocking. Maybe you have a transaction that is still open and as such the select statement(s) in your procedure are simply waiting for the resource locks to be removed. If you can provide some code we can probably help. But as it sits right now we are just guessing.

Comment: I created the sproc. But it wouldn't compile the data, so i removed just went to alter the code and removed the parameters and such and just put in example parameters using declare and set. i will look into the blocking and understanding what is happening better. Ill report back. thanks

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has to take out locks on the objects so it can create a query plan. It either cannot connect to the database or cannot take the locks it needs.

Comment: sorry, i am fairly new, and dont quite understand the locks. Can you clarify what they are and how i would check for this issue